# Create URL for external site with GET parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, get

I'm making a Tweet This link in Rails. The URL I need to generate looks something like this:

```
http://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&text=Hello%20World
```

but a bit more complex. Basically a URL with a load of GET parameters appended

It would be nice to use one of Rails' helpers, to generate this link, something like:

```
url_for("http://twitter.com/share", :url => "http://example.com", :text => "Hello world")
```

But I haven't found anything that works. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you could write your own helper for this quite fast

Comment: True, but I wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel if it's already possible in Rails

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can call `to_query` on Hash in rails which will take care of url encoding etc.  So maybe something like this:

```
params = {
  :a => "http://google.com",
  :b => 123
}
url = "http://example.com?#{params.to_query}"
```

Comment: thank you for posting this, it just helped me fix a nightmare bug

Comment: That work perfect! The unique problem is that it only works when you use " ", with ' ' it doesn't work. I know that it's not a problem, but rails prefers using ' ' to " "

Comment: @msj That is because Ruby string interpolation does not work with single quotes, since single quotes don't get parsed. In other words, it's because of Ruby that #{} won't get interpolated in single quotes.

Comment: @D.Visser Absolutely.

Comment: Is there anything built in that constructs a URL for an external site with parameters in the URL itself (as in something like `http://example.com/:id/show`, where `:id` is a parameter)? I've been trying to find something similar to the rails `_path` and `_url` methods created for routes so I can use it for an external site.

Answer (score 3):

I like Brian's answer. Here it is in the form of a method, in case anyone else comes across this.

```
  def url_with_attributes_from_hash(url = "", attr_hash = {})
    url == "" or attr_hash == {} ? "#{url.to_s}" : "#{url.to_s}?#{attr_hash.to_query}"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own helper for this would be one simple line of code:

```
def twitter_url_for(url, text)
  link_to "Share this url", "http://twitter.com/share?url=#{url}&text=#{text}"
end
```

Comment: This puts the options as HTML attributes: `<a url="http://example.com" text="Hello World" href="http://twitter.com/share">Share this url</a>`

Comment: My bad, I was getting the link to options mixed up with a named route. Sorry about that. I just updated it with something that should work.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but wouldn't this url have spaces in it or does link_to automatically deal with converting to a query string and converting any special characters and such? EDIT: Never mind...it does...answered my own question.

Comment: This is tempting, but it very quickly blows up in terms of size and complexity. If you're passing up an array, or a float, for instance, you start to hit reserved characters and have to try and sanitize those.